# d3.js: efficient filtering of large selection

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Given a large selection (several tens of thousands) I want to filter for one or more element matching given IDs.

For them moment, I use something like that:

```
var ids = [1, 42, …, 13];
var idsObj = arrayToObject(ids); // { 1: 1, 42: 1, …, 13: 1 }

var filteredSelection = theSelection.filter(function(d) {
    return idsObj[d.id];
});
```

What I do not like about that solution is that the runtime does not really depend on the amount of IDs. It iterates over the whole selection regardless of whether all IDs have been found already.

Is there a way to manually iterate over the selection? I've already `theSelection.each()`, however it seems like there is no way to break the iteration.
Or do you know another approach?

**EDIT:**
Maybe I can work with something like that:

```
for (var i = 0; i < theSelection[0].length; i++) {
    // d3.select(theSelection[0][i]).datum().id
};
```

Comment: if you have the theSelection, then you can simply iterate it with plain loop.

Comment: The way I did in the edited post?

Comment: Yeah, that is what I meant.:)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I've got a solution. Please comment, if there is an even better way ;)

```
var filteredNodes = [];

for (var i = 0; i < theSelection[0].length; i++) {
    var el = theSelection[0][i];
    var d = d3.select(el).datum();

    if (idsObj[d.id]) {
        filteredNodes.push(el);

        if (filteredNodes.length == ids.length) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

var filteredSelection = d3.selectAll(filteredNodes);
```

By the way, is it possible to do something like that:

```
var filteredSelection = d3.select();

for (…) {
    …
    filteredSelection.add(el);
    …
}
```